# Best way of Authentication in Spring REST application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I have a question about authentication in Spring Boot REST application. 
I create small and simple application with user registration and login for practice Spring Rest, Spring Boot, Spring Data and future React. 
What is best way to authentication user in those type of applications?

I found this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-1/

Tutorial use JWT. Is there any other way to secure rest application and with of these ways are best for small application?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I think [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrGbh.png) posted in [Best Way For Token Validation in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989302/best-way-for-token-validation-in-angular/49030510#49030510) can give you a general picture about how this flow should be in a decoupled application (Spring boot REST services + client, where client can be react, angular, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to implement security like

- You can use custom token based implementation, you can create a custom token that you can store in DB but JWT is a good choice.
- OAuth

You can refer [this link](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/jwt-role-based-authorization.) for Role based custom implementation using JWT solution

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) you have a link to the official tutorial regarding Spring Security

I would encourage you to use annotations instead of XML files.